# How to run multiple instances of jetty with maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty, instances

So, what I want to do is configure maven plugin jetty to run multiple - in my case two - instances of jetty server on different ports and with different apps.

So, I want to have something like:

```
localhost:8080/webapp1
localhost:8081/webapp2
```

And I want to do this with one single command: mvn jetty:run
which of course means that I have to configure it in pom.xml

I already have two different jetty config files: jettyA.xml and jettyB.xml in which there are different connectors defined.
The problem is just i can't figure it out how to do this with one pom.xml

I tried with two profiles but is somehow did not work.
Just jetty in the last profile mentioned was started.

Comment: This might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519066/possible-to-run-two-webapps-at-once-when-developing-with-maven-eclipse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the port number in pom.xml by a property variable like this:

```
<port>${jetty.port}</port>
```

Then run maven using the following command:

```
mvn jetty:run -Djetty.port=8081
```

To define a default port numer, add this default property to your pom file:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.port>8080</jetty.port>
</properties>
```

If you need any more advanced method for determining the port number, you will need to embed jetty in your main class.

Comment: Yes.. i know how to set the port for jetty server..  and if i am running jetty from two different projects with each it's own POM.XML i can do what i described... BUT i want to do this in a new project with only ONE POM.XML file... so but I can't figure it out how to set two different jetty.xml file in this ONE POM.XML

Answer (score 2):

This is the way that I sorted the above issue

1.)Go to your **Run** -> **Run Configurations** or **Debug Configurations** in eclipse or STS
(I used STS)

2.)then Dialog box will be appear & in left side menu Double Click on the **Maven Build**

3.)in top of the Right Side under **Name** Text phase Enter Anyname which you want
    Ex:- Jetty_Server

4.)below select **Browse Workspace** then select your project which you want to clean intall & run with jetty server (i think you already added  jetty plugin in your pom file)

5.) below in **Goal** text box enter below line (you can use 8020 or 8065 or any port)

```
clean install -Djetty.port=8020 jetty:run
```

6.)then **configure** the maven runtime (select where is installed your maven folder)

7.)then **apply** -> **Run/Debug**

Answer (score 1):

OK, i solved this like this...

I have one POM.XML file with two different profiles.
Then i wrote a SH script.. in which I run both profiles like this:

```
mvn jetty:run-war -Pprofile1 &
mvn jetty:run-war -Pprofile2
```

In each profile I have it's own config file (jettyA.xml, jettyB.xml) in wich there are two servers defined on different ports - with different apps.

Now All i have to do is run one SH script and that is it.