# Restart jetty server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty, vaadin

I've more than one project in eclipse which require jetty server (I use maven).
I run project1 with no problem. Then I want to turn off **project1** 
and/or just normally start **project2**. I'm getting error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.9.v20160517:run (default-cli) on project PROJECT2: Failure: Address already in use: bind -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

How may I restart/rerun jetty server? The problem is in engaged port (localhost:8080).
First solution is to restart elipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the projects concurrently, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591055/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-jetty-with-maven#answer-12591599). Basically, you'll need to configure the port in one (or both) of the projects' pom.xml so that the ports in the Jetty Maven plugin don't conflict.

If you only want to run one project at a time, just be sure to stop the Eclipse debugger before starting the next by clicking on the red "stop" button [image: red stop button image]. When I forget to do this, I just kill the corresponding java processes.