# How to 'mvn jetty:run' from a parent pom?

Tags: maven, jetty

I have a multi-module project that includes several .war packages.  I would like to be able to 'mvn jetty:run' on the parent pom and have each of the sub-modules's .wars deployed on the same embedded jetty instance.

I am able to successfully run 'mvn jetty:run' from each of the the sub-modules, but when I run it on the parent pom it fails and skips the sub-modules.

Trying to run 'mvn jetty:run' from the parent pom results in the following:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.16:run default-cli) on
>   project FlashCards_App: Webapp source directory C:\dev\sour
>   ce_code\FlashCards_App\src\main\webapp does not exist -> [Help 1]

It's true there is no webapp directory on the parent pom.

Here's an excerpt from my pom.  The full file can be [found here](https://github.com/justinhrobbins/FlashCards_App/blob/e9e613e94051ba55bf1eaaa05a45438931c8fa84/pom.xml).

```
<modules>
    <module>FlashCards_Domain</module>
    <module>FlashCards_GWT</module>
    <module>FlashCards_Service</module>
    <module>FlashCards_Service_SpringData</module>
    <module>FlashCards_Service_Jpa</module>
    <module>FlashCards_WebServices</module>
    <module>FlashCards_Struts</module>
    <module>FlashCards_Test</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is basically the same question asked in 2009 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639616/how-do-i-deploy-multiple-peer-webapps-from-a-parent-pom).  It's been a few years and I'm wondering if there are any other options available now.  The previous post proposes two solutions (1) using cargo plugin and (2) building sister wars from a sub-module.

Comment: Due to lack of being able to give an authoritative answer, I rather post this as a comment: I don't think this is gonna fly. You could possibly code the heck out of plugins and such, but I think it'd be an awkward solution at best. How about making another project that depends on the others, just for this purpose? It could [assemble](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) the dependencies into place if needed, and run that single Jetty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best shot is probably to configure the jetty plugin to [run multiple webapps](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#running-more-than-one-webapp). I'm not sure if it would work from your parent pom though, so you might have to use on of your modules as the "launcher" webapp, or create a "dummy webapp" in your parent project.

Answer (score 2):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.6.v20141205</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <contextHandlers>
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                        <war>${project.basedir}/app1/target/app1.war</war>
                        <contextPath>/app1</contextPath>
                    </contextHandler>
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                        <war>${project.basedir}/app2/target/app2.war</war>
                        <contextPath>/app2</contextPath>
                    </contextHandler>
                </contextHandlers>
                <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
                <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

> cd parent_module
>   mvn jetty:run -pl sub_module

Comment: please provide some explanation for your answer so that future visitors can know what it is about

Comment: I think it's compendious

Answer (score 0):

> cd parent_module
>   mvn jetty:run -pl sub_module

To complete [@jiahut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517100/jiahut) answer:

```
$ mvn jetty:run --help
(...)
-am,--also-make                        If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects required by the
                                        list
-amd,--also-make-dependents            If project list is specified, also
                                        build projects that depend on
                                        projects on the list
(...)
-pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified 
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path
```

Example from [Apache Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/developers/building.html):

```
mvn jetty:run -pl :archiva-webapp -am
```